# Select the value of a not selected option by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I query some data from my database and want to preselect the select option depending on my loaded data.
My plan was to get the value of an not selected option by his id and then set the select value to the option value.

E.g.

I got from my database the id `11`. Therefore I try to get the value `5` and set it afterwards as my selected value for the whole select `dish`.

```js
function doStuff(){
  //Try to get the value here
  $("#dish").val("received value from above")
}
```

```html
<select id="dish" onload="doStuff()">
    <option value="">-----</option>
    <option id="4" value="4">Cheese</option>
    <option id="11" value="5">Ham</option>
    <option id="19" value="6">Fries</option>
    <option id="31" value="7">Soup</option>
</select>
```

Is there any solution to achive this with `jQuery` or `JavaScript`?

Comment: So you want the value of id 11? Then use `$("#dish option#11").val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would exploit the power of [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) + [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect)  and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to reflect changes to an object property right into the DOM.

Here's an example that:
proxyies an Object and reflects changes to the element by `data-*` attribute that matches the prop in question (`"dish"` in this specific case)

```js
const X = (ob) => Object.assign(new Proxy(ob, {
  set(targ, p, v, recv) {
    const Rs = Reflect.set(targ, p, v, recv);
    render(p, v);
    return Rs;
  }
}), ob);
const render = (p, v) => $(`[data-prop="${p}"]`).val(v);

// Here's the server data:
const serverData = {dish: 5};

// Create a proxy (Will init changes to DOM thanks to Object.assign())
const myData = X(serverData);

// Example: Update dynamically (wait 3 and see it happen)
setTimeout(() => myData.dish = 7, 3000);

// More examples: Open console and set another value to myData.dish like i.e:
// myData.dish = 4
```

```html
The value is added on DOM ready and.<br>
Wait for 3 sec to see a dynamic change:<br>
<select data-prop="dish">
  <option value="">-----</option>
  <option value="4">Cheese</option>
  <option value="5">Ham</option>
  <option value="6">Fries</option>
  <option value="7">Soup</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onload` event is not applicable for the select element, here I added a code sample to set the select option based on the id while page load.

```js
var valueFromDb="11";

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#dish').val($('#dish #'+valueFromDb).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dish" >
    <option value="">-----</option>
    <option id="4" value="4">Cheese</option>
    <option id="11" value="5">Ham</option>
    <option id="19" value="6">Fries</option>
    <option id="31" value="7">Soup</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **{selected:true}** as prop for select option like below,

```
function doStuff(){
  let id="11"
   $(`#${id}`).prop('selected', true);
}
```